# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Eclipse C++ Remote Application

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries, remote-server

I'm developing a synchronized project with Eclipse CDT where opencv is used.

The local run configuration gives you the opportunity to set variables in the Environment tab, so I can define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as I like.

However, for a Remote C++ Application, there isn't an Environment tab and I can't set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so there is an `undefined reference` error at runtime.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Show your remote debug launch configuration. Where are you looking for **Environment tab**?. Which CDT version?Which type of CDT project you created?How?